# Android consuming a part of purchase only

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I analysed [official docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume) about this but there is mentioned only that user can consume purchase after he is own it, using:

`mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);`

or method `consume(Purchase itemInfo)` from `IabHelper`

Is there a way to consume a part of it only, let's say 10% and so on?

If I have a game and user spends only 10/100 coins I can't consume all 100 at once.

Answer (score 0):

In-app Billing API 3 doesn't support quantity - a user owns SKU or doesn't (just two states + subscriptions).

You have to handle quantity in your back-end.

Check example [TrivialDrive](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive), there is the same idea with gas, just mirror purchases states for robustness and security in the back-end.